# android:shape="line" not visible

Tags: android, android-layout, shapedrawable

I have the following drawable shape:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:shape="line" >

   <stroke
      android:width="1dp"
      android:color="#e0e0e0" />

</shape>
```

And use this with this image:

```
  <ImageView
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="1dp"
     android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
     android:src="@drawable/line" />
```

When I set `android:layout_height` to 1dp, the shape is not visible. If the `android:layout_height` is set to 2dp, the shape is visible.

Why do I have to use a height of 2dp?

Ralph

Comment: Possible answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/26296229/185022

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a stroke, so it goes around the shape. Meaning it passes the line on both sides, so it will need twice the width of the stroke.

You could just set `<size>` tag in your shape and put that on 1dp and `<solid android:color="">` for the color

Comment: I try it :-)
But the documentation says:
"line" A horizontal line that spans the width of the containing View. This shape requires the <stroke> element to define the width of the line.